# d3.next.rollup returns undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a data structure like this (CSV-File):

```
Datum,Name,Kategorie,Betrag
01/10/15,,Lohn,1586.7
02/10/15,,lunch,-4.55
02/10/15,kaisla,Ausgehen,-16.2
```

What I'm trying to do is to sum up by Date like this.

```
var summedData = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.Datum;})
  .rollup(function(v) { return {
    date: v.Datum,
    total: d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.Betrag; }),
    category: v.Kategorie}; 
  })
  .entries(data);
```

however this returns an object like this:

```
object{
  key: "01/10/2015"
  values: object{
    date: undefined
    category: undefined
    sum: 1586.7
  }
}
```

I don't figure why the `date` and `category` is undefined and how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

In your `.rollup`, `v` is an array so, `v.Datum` and `v.Kategorie` are *undefined*.  Doing something like this:

```
return {
  date: v[0].Datum,
  ...
```

Will work for `Datum` since it'll repeat and be unique, but `Kategorie` won't, so how about:

```
category: v.map(function(d){
  return d.Kategorie;
})
```

Of course this depends on your end goal.

---

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var data = [{"Datum":"01/10/15","Name":"","Kategorie":"Lohn","Betrag":"1586.7"},{"Datum":"02/10/15","Name":"","Kategorie":"lunch","Betrag":"-4.55"},{"Datum":"02/10/15","Name":"kaisla","Kategorie":"Ausgehen","Betrag":"-16.2"}];
    
    var summedData = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.Datum;
      })
      .rollup(function(v) {
        return {
          date: v[0].Datum,
          total: d3.sum(v, function(d) {
            return d.Betrag;
          }),
          category: v.map(function(d){
            return d.Kategorie;
          })
        };
      })
      .entries(data);
      
    console.log(summedData);

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```